# how consume via Suds a webservice that expose wsdl via https and service via http

Tags: python, soap, suds

I've a strange situation to solve (imho)

I've to consume a web service who has the wsdl via https and the service via http.
How I can "switch" on-the-fly (in Suds) to http only for the service?

Thank's

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can write custom transport, but in your situation it's much simpler to download wsdl locally.

```
import requests
import suds    

r = requests.get(SERVICE_WSDL_HTTPS_URL)
with open('/tmp/service.wsdl', 'w') as file:
    file.write(r.text)
client = suds.client.Client('file:///tmp/service.wsdl', location=SERVICE_HTTP_URL)
```